# Select From Table with Multiple Rows for some ID's, with an identifier value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the following results:

```
ID    Location
1     NYC
1     LA
2     NYC
3     PIT
```

and I'd like the following:

```
ID    Location
1     Multiple
2     NYC
3     PIT
```

Does anyone know an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `case` with `count` and `distinct`:

```
select distinct id, 
  case when count(location) over (partition by id ) > 1 
    then 'Multiple' else location end Location
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdc51/1)

Answer (score 0):

With `sub-query`, `COUNT`, `CASE`, `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT mm.id, CASE WHEN mm.count > 1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE loc END As Location
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(id) As count, id, MAX(location) As loc
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id) As mm;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63c6a/14)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,case when MIN(name) = MAX(name) then  MIN(name) else 'multiple' end as Location
from <your tabel name>
group by id
```